# java elasticsearch query without java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I try to query an existing elasticsearch base in java without using the Java API.
This elasticsearch base belongs to an ELK cluster.

The correct cURL query is :

```
curl -XGET 'http://10.60.74.134:9200/logstash-2015.04.09/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "facets": {
    "0": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "5m"
      },
      "global": true,
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                          "from": 1428558001338,
                          "to": 1428579601338
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "_type": [
                          "akaoatg-monitoring"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

which works perfectly fine and returns me my JSON results :

```
{
  "took" : 185,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 9106263,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "0" : {
      "_type" : "date_histogram",
      "entries" : [ {
        "time" : 1428458700000,
        "count" : 2429
      }, {
        "time" : 1428459000000,
        "count" : 21128
      }, {
        "time" : 1428459300000,
        "count" : 21354
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to get the same results using an http request in java :

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.60.74.134:9200/logstash-2015.04.09/_search?pretty'-d'{\"facets\":{\"terms\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"_type\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"count\",\"exclude\":[]},\"facet_filter\":{\"fquery\":{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"should\":[{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\"}}]}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"from\":1428558001341,\"to\":1428579601341}}},{\"terms\":{\"_type\":[\"akaoatg-monitoring\"]}}]}}}}}}}},\"size\":0}");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String strTemp;
            while((strTemp = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(strTemp);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The URL I am using here is the cURL request formatted to fit in an http request.
This request returns me a single String which does not contain the same result.
here is a part of the java result :

```
   {"took":22,
"timed_out":false,
"_shards":{"total":5,
"successful":5,
"failed":0},
"hits":{"total":4621367,
"max_score":1.0,
"hits":[{"_index":"logstash-2015.04.09",
"_type":"xxx",
"_id":"xxx",
"_score":xxx,
"_source":{"@version":"xxx",
"@timestamp":"2015-04-09T01:09:59.347Z",
"host":"xxx",
"type":"xxx",
"sys_priority":"xxx",
"sys_timestamp":"xxx",
"logsource":"xxx",
"application":"xxx",
"year":"2015",
"month":"04",
"day":"09",
"hour":"01",
"minute":"09",
"second":"58",
"trace_level":"3",
"host_name":"xxx",
"adh_port":"xxx",
"timestamp_adh":1428541798954,
"time_adh":27,
"adh_uuid":"xxx",
"Service":"xxx",
"ReturnCode":"0",
"ErrorMessage":"null",
"Site":"null",
"BaseType":"null",
"PlatForm":"0",
"Cad_sender":"",
"Domain":"xxx",
"Freshness":"9",
"ClientProcessID":"xxx",
"CallMode":"S",
"SystemMode":"R",
"Sad_receiver":"",
"ConnectionType":"IP",
"DataFormat":"",
"HeaderType":"H4",
"AdhesionVersion":"null",
"Length":"10",
"ConnectionInfo":"null",
"ConnectionInfoKey":"null",
"Comments":"null",
"ActionCode":"null",
"TimeStamp":20150409010958,
"ServerProgramName":"null",
"TransactionCode":"null",
"TraceLevel":"null",
"LU":"null",
"HostName":"xxx",
"Port":"xxx",
"Timer":20,
"SendQueue":"null",
"ReturnQueue":"",
"PDM":"",
"RFU":"null",
"FTU":"",
"ActivationFlag":"null",
"HistoryQueue":"null",
"ErrorQueue":"null",
"CallReference":"xxx",
"IPAddress":"xxx",
"MessageType":"I",
"ProgramName":"null",
"UserName":"xxx",
"BeginTime":"24:00:00",
"EndTime":"24:00:00",
"duration":0,
"cnx_running":0,
"cnx_max":0}}]}}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will not work that way, instead you could try Apache client as a solution that will send a post request

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to get results using only java ?

Comment: can you at least anonymize the string which you get as the result? It can work like that, of course (ElasticSearch supports REST API after all), so there might be something else which is wrong. One thing to check: if you print out that URL you generate, will it produce a valid query? You can try copy-paste it into something like Sense plugin.

Comment: apache client is a java library for example, so you could use java for getting results

Comment: @Ashalynd I added an anonymized string in the post

Comment: @Ashalynd I tried the Sense plugin, but what exactly do you want me to try ? Pasting only the server address and port in the server field returns me a lot of information about the ES base, but adding the rest of the URL gives me an error _Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):undefined_ .
The URL has to be valid as my java code manages to reach it and get a result, only not the good one...

Comment: It looks like the search request sent from Java is misunderstood by the server, which make me think that there could be some formatting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the type of request, I had to send a POST request instead of a GET one.
Used this code :

```
String url = "http://10.60.74.134:9200/logstash-2015.04.09/_search?pretty'-d'";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "{\"facets\":{\"0\":{\"date_histogram\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"interval\":\"5m\"},\"global\":true,\"facet_filter\":{\"fquery\":{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\"}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"from\":1428558001338,\"to\":1428579601338}}},{\"terms\":{\"_type\":[\"akaoatg-monitoring\"]}}]}}}}}}}},\"size\":0}";
```

thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/#)

Answer (score 0):

Your request sent via Java is malformed: there is no "facets": { "0": {...}} part in it. (At least the '0' is missing). Hence the server seems to ignore that part and just give you a bunch of raw entries (the default output)

Comment: You are right, I probably deleted that part unintentionally when formatting the request. I still get the same result however.
Maybe it is due to the request type (GET, POST), I'm going to explore that further.